# reinstall Intel Wireless-AX200 drivers on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi

part of the output of: `sudo lshw -class network`

```
description: Wireless interface

       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200

       vendor: Intel Corporation
```

I bought a new gaming laptop: HP Omen 15 and have Ubuntu 20.04 installed. I need to reinstall the networking module/driver for it since the network driver will throw errors repeatedly until the computer malfunctions and cannot shut off properly (the computer breaks down with no sudo and no internet at around 10 minutes after login). I would like the drivers/modules to be at whatever it was upon installation of Ubuntu 20.04.

How can I do this? What do I need to install/reinstall?

Here is a print out of the kernel ring buffer and info from kernel module when wireless is turned on (when everything is normal and I have not lost sudo and internet yet):

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    8.349423] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.358387] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.358411] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.585992] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    8.585995] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    8.585996] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    8.586191] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    9.286866] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    9.301416] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    9.301738] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    9.474872] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: base HW address: f8:e4:e3:f0:46:ff
[    9.496589] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[  424.251632] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[  424.418297] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[  424.435344] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep filename
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
```

Here is the output of `dmesg| grep iwl` when the computer is "screaming" and I have lost sudo, the fan starts whirring and internet fails.

```
[ 5428.224879]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.225057]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.225238]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.225421]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.225600]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.225779]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.225957]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.226135]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.226318]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.226540]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.226720]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.226900]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.227079]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.227258]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.227438]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.227616]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.227795]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.227993]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.228186]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.228369]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.228552]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.228731]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.228909]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.229091]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.229154] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.229272]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.229335] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.229452]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.229514] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.229630]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.229693] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.229811]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.229874] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.229990]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.230052] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.230169]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.230231] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.230370]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.230452] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.230568]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.230630] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.230746]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.230808] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.230925]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.230987] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.231103]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.231165] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.231282]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.231344] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.231461]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.231523] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.231639]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.231702] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.231819]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.231882] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.232002]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.232065] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.232275]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.232337] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.232507]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.232628] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.233253]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.233399] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.233624]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.233736] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.233903]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.234104]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.234169] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.234361]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.234463] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.234588]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[ 5428.234654] Modules linked in: ccm iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 iwlwifi cfg80211 rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda nvidia(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_compress ac97_bus x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev aesni_intel btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic crypto_simd ecc cryptd intel_pch_thermal snd_seq mc rtsx_pci_ms mei_hdcp snd_seq_device
[ 5428.234781]  ? iwl_mvm_set_tim+0x50/0x50 [iwlmvm]

...
```

Comment: Please run the terminal command: `dmesg | grep iwl` and also: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep filename` Next, edit your question to show the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and additional information. It will be impossible to troubleshoot the issue when the `dmesg` listing is only when the card and driver are working well. Are there further clues here? `cat /var/log/syslog | grep iwl` If not, try the same but syslog.1. As the output will be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Here is the link to the NVIDIA forums where I have shared my kernel log and some one has identified that my network card is causing the issue: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/hp-omen15-and-ubuntu-20-04-and-nvidia-drivers-not-working/122468

Comment: Thanks so much for 1.8 GB of logs to study. Here are some interesting snips: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qfv6GCdyMw/ A search for those terms yields nothing useful. Can you boot into an earlier kernel version at the GRUB menu and if so, is the performance correct? Which kernel version fixes it? Also, please try a driver parameter and see if it helps. If so, we'll make it permanent: `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` followed by: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi disable_11ac=Y disable_11ax=Y`

Comment: Well an earlier kernel version of  5.4.0-26-generic from 5.4.0-29-generic works but it is disabling the GPU ("nvidia-smi has failed..."). acpi=off is not used in GRUB file. The whole point of buying my laptop was to use the GPU in Linux. I also tried the two commands with ```modprobe``` you suggested, but they did not fix the issue. Is it possible to reinstall the networking  firmware or drivers?

Comment: You might try: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms` followed by a reboot. I suspect that this will not help but let's try. If it doesn't help, then: `sudo purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms` followed by a reboot.

Comment: sudo: purge: command not found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107849/discussion-between-chili555-and-user352102).